# How do you append a current URL string to an image URL only using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Silly question but I would like to create or set an image src that appends the current url after a string.

So I would like to write

```
<img src="//testURL.comaction?item={www.currenturl.com}" id="tabUrl" />
```

So {www.currenturl.com} will be replaced with the current URL

I know that I can get the current URL by `using window.location.href;` but how can I add this to a string?

Not sure if I should create a variable and apply it using document.getElementById

```
taboo = window.location.href;
```

Or do a document write similar to the example below

```
<script>document.write('<img src="'//testURL.comaction?item= + 
window.location.href + '">')</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the two approaches you've laid out? Do they not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are a bit off: try this

```
'<img src=//testURL.comaction?item=' + window.location.href + '>'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want a pure JS way to do the same, I would recommend following.

```
var string="testURL.comaction?item="+window.location.href;
document.getElementsByTagName("img").setAttribute("src", string);
```

Comment: I used your example and no changes were made to my code `<img src="" width="0" height="0" style="display: none" id="tabUrl" /> `